# Scroll both columns as one

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My app has two columns, left side being a textarea, while the right side is the result calculated from the text area. But my result column would overflow the fixed window, while textarea would scroll by default. [image: Result column overflows]

So I've tried to set both the whole row and its parent to `overflow: auto`, which let me scroll when I've got enough input, but at the expense of having my separator not full height as well as having a delay after I've wrote into my textarea, before the dix snaps into a bigger height...[image: first attempt]

My final solution was to use JS & Jquery to check when content is overflown, to alternate between `height: auto` when it is and `height: 100%` when its not. That also kinda worked, but with wonky delays yet again...

```
const editor_js = document.querySelector('.editor');
const $editor = $('.editor');

$('.input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  console.log('Textarea changed');
  if(editor_js.offsetHeight < editor_js.scrollHeight){
    $editor.css("height", "auto");
  }
  else{
    $editor.css("height", "100%");
  }
});
```

Anyways I am at my wits end. I just want to have my columns consistently scrollable as one entity, while keeping the separator full height at all times. Hope you can give me some suggestions. If you want to directly do some attempts at my app, here's the [link](http://nlp-calculator.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you add overflow:hidden  on the text area and overflow:scroll on the parent of both sides?

This way you can scroll both columns at once even if only one of them requires it.

Comment: @FlorinSimion You'll end up with missing (hidden) input in the text area...

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your current working demo? It will be much easier to help you if I can see what you are doing with your HTML and CSS. For what you want I don't think you need to resort to JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for you to get that effect would be to add that vertical border as a pseudo element on the parent. When I say simple, I mean it would be easy to set it and forget it. CSS would deal with it and it would be independant of the size

Answer (score -2):

I think your best option will be to calculate the height of your text area in javascript and set the css style to it.

Then, Make sure you have the following css:

```
textarea.col-9.input {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.main-body .editor {
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
.col-lg-5.col-md-7.col-sm-8.main-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried it in Chrome's developer tools and it works well.

Comment: As I've mentioned this doesn't work as intended, input gets hidden. Here's what I mean: https://imgur.com/a/s79wL

Comment: I know what you meant...Have a look at my result here.
https://giphy.com/gifs/test-textareia-xUOxfbiNXnzTr11bEY

Comment: Well that's weird, I cannot reproduce what you've done, nor in my own code nor through Chrome dev tools...

Comment: Make sure you use the css rules I've mentioned, plus you need to add some height to textarea.col-9.input 
You can add some manually to test it out (i've added like 4000px or so), but of course you will need to set that dynamically in javascript later.